# Face recognition using PCA solution :D 11951

Tags: c#

> it image grabber

```
 void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    numberOfFace.Text = "0";

    NamePersons.Add("");


    //Get the current frame form capture device
    currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

    //Convert it to Grayscale
    gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

    //Face Detector
    MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(face,1.2,2,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20));

//Action for each element detected
foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
{
t = t + 1;
result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
//draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Red), 2);





    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
    {
    //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

    //Eigen face recognizer
    EigenObjRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjRecognizer(
    trainingImages.ToArray(),
    labels.ToArray(),
    10000,
    ref termCrit);

    name = recognizer.Recognize(result);



    //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
    currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new System.Drawing.Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen));

    }
```

NamePersons[t - 1] = name;
    NamePersons.Add("");

```
  //Set the number of faces detected on the scene
    numberOfFace.Text = facesDetected[0].Length.ToString();

    /*
    //Set the region of interest on the faces

    gray.ROI = f.rect;
    MCvAvgComp[][] eyesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
    eye,
    1.1,
        10,
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
        new Size(20, 20));
        gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

        foreach (MCvAvgComp ey in eyesDetected[0])
        {
        Rectangle eyeRect = ey.rect;
        eyeRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
        currentFrame.Draw(eyeRect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
        }
        */

        }


 t = 0;

    //Names concatenation of persons recognized
    for (int nnn = 0; nnn < facesDetected[0].Length; nnn++)
    {
    names = names + NamePersons[nnn] + ", ";
    }
    //Show the faces procesed and recognized
    image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);
    nameOfFace.Text = names;
    names = "";
    //Clear the list(vector) of names
    NamePersons.Clear();

    }
```

as I have written some comment you can learn how this will work :) 
hope you enjoy that :D
Face Recognition Using PCA algorithm and eigenfaces

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you followed any examples?   Have you googled or just posted your homework question here in the hopes someone does it for you?

Comment: Who wrote this rubbish? Postfix *always* means putting the operator after the operands. There is no mention of right recursion here. Most arithmetic operations are left-associative, so right-recursion is not appropriate. Naked homework dump. Off topic.

Comment: You are right, you have to write the grammar first and then delve into the other tasks (post fix -- which should be easier, print, parse trees, predictive functions, some sort of program, error grammar, etc).   Its a big assignment to get right and complete.   Good luck, hope the example helps.

Comment: What do you have done so far?   My example is not the answer to your homework, it simply shows you what sort of thing they are looking for.   If you can't figure it out, you are better off failing out of the course and pursuing an alternate path.   As I have often told my 6 year old, helping doesn't mean doing it for you.  It means assisting when you occasionally stumble.   I haven't done grammars for 20+ years and used google to provide you some guidance.   Time for you to take your first step.   Review your text, classnotes, online resources, and do it.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Grammars can look like this :

```
Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
Sign -> + | -
Integer -> (sign) Digit {Digit}
Float -> Integer (. (Integer))
EFloat -> Float E Integer
```

Define your symbols...

```
{} = zero or more instances of this
() = one optional instance of this
```

Then use the pieces to build formulae

```
Expression = Integer
Expression = Float
Expression = Expression * Expression
Expression = Expression + Expression
Expression = Expression - Expression
Expression = Expression / Expression
...
Expression = ( Expression )
```

Depending on how you build things you get various grammar.   The one above is an example and (hopefully) clearly contains mistakes.